# Can a vector be integrated with respect to another vector?

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors

I know it is possible to differentiate a vector with respect to another vector. However this left me wondering if it is possible to integrate a vector with respect to another vector. Such as for example:
$$ \int \vec{v} \space d\vec{v} $$
Where $\vec{v}$ is a unknown vector. Is this or something similar possible? If yes under what conditions?

Comment: Completely devoid of the typical context for vector notation, I'd think this was $\frac{({\vec{v}})^2}{2}$, which surely makes no sense in that context, but I'm excited to see what others say.

Comment: what kind of product $v\ dv$ do you have in mind?

Comment: @Jonas Could you clarify what you mean by differentiating a vector with respect to another vector?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Vector-by-vector

Comment: As janmarqz asked, what type of vector product do you intend?  There are two ways to multiply two vectors- dot product and cross product.

Comment: I don't know what $\vec{v}{\rm d}\vec{v}$ is supposed to mean here, but I can say that something similar to this often pop up when integrating over surfaces (and in many other situations), though with a dot-product between the integrating vector and the differential. See for example [Stokes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%E2%80%93Stokes_theorem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As janmarqz asked, what type of vector product do you intend?  There are two ways to multiply two vectors- dot product and cross product.  If you mean dot product then, writing $\vec{v}= <x, y, z>$ and $d\vec{v}= <dx, dy, dz>$, then $\int \vec{v}\cdot d\vec{v}= \int xdx+ ydy+ zdz= \frac{1}{2}(x^2+ y^2+ z^2)+ C$.

If you mean the cross product, then $\vec{v}\times d\vec{v}= (ydz- zdy)\vec{i}+ (zdx- xdz)\vec{j}+ (xdy- ydx)\vec{k}$.  Since the integrals of each component is yz- zy= 0, zx- xz= 0, and xy- yx= 0, $\int \vec{v}\times d\vec{v}= \vec{0}$, the 0 vector.  (More simply, $\vec{v}$ and $d\vec{v}$ are vectors in the same direction so their cross product is the 0 vector.)

Comment: Can it also be done for the Hadamard product?

Comment: n i c e . . . .

Comment: The "Hadamard Product" of vectors <x, y, z> and <dx, dy, dz> is [itex]\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} dx & dy & dz\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} xdx & xdy & xdz \\ ydx & ydy & ydz \\ zdx & zdy & zdz\end{bmatrix}[/itex].  Integrating that, we get [tex]\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2}x^2+ C_1 & xy+ C_2 & xz+ C_3 \\ xy+ C_4 & \frac{1}{2}y^2+ C_5 & yz+ C_6\\ xz+ C_7 & yz+ C_8 & \frac{1}{2}z^2+ C_9 \end{bmatrix}[tex].

Answer (score 2):

As said by others in the comments, to answer this question we must first specify what kind of product is intended between the differential $d\vec{v}$ and the integrand. If the product we have in mind is the *dot product*, then this integral indeed exists.

Let $\vec{F}:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ be a vector field. Then the integral
$$\int_\gamma\vec{F}(\vec{v})\cdot d\vec{v}$$
where $\gamma$ is a path in $\mathbb R^n$, can be defined. If we interpret $\gamma$ as the path of a particle and we interpret $\vec{F}$ as a force, then an intuitive interpretation of this integral is as the continuous sum of forces acting on the particle as it travels along its path. This is a physical quantity known as *work*, which is extremely useful in physics.