# Can you define a tensor by integrating one vector with respect to another?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, tensor-products, tensors

I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3280160/can-a-vector-be-integrated-with-respect-to-another-vector) question, simply I was wondering about integrating a vector with respect to another vector field. In the question, the OP asks if the following quantity has any sensible meaning:
$$\int\vec{v}\space d\vec{v}$$

Thinking more generally about the (potentially ill-defined) quantity
$$\int\vec{w}\space d\vec{v}$$ for vector fields $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$, can we assign this to be a tensor (or otherwise a two indice object)? My first thought was maybe it doesn't transform properly, but perhaps there is a workaround with some maths tricks I'm not aware of? I was thinking of defining it in the sense that we would have
$$T_{ij}=\int w_i\space dv_j$$The prior question only considered the notion of it being a dot-product, or a cross product, so I felt like this justified being it's own question.

Comment: Also I'm not 100% certain on what the appropriate tags are on Math.SE, so apologies if they are at all misleading - I know mathematicians are (as they should be) particular about classifying these things

Comment: What kind of integral is this? Definite / indefinite ?  Integrals of the form $\int_\gamma \vec{w}\cdot d\vec{v}$ are not ill-defined. They are known as line integrals since many hundret years. One questions in the linked post (unforuntately not the accepted one) speaks about that.

Comment: I know what line integrals are - I was suggesting some kind of tensor product type object (as I mentioned in the question). The choice of definite/indefinite can be chosen if it helps make the object in question more useful, or if any potential answerer has knows of such a case. I was thinking maybe you could define it as the line integral along the shortest geodesic between some constant point $p \in M$ and some varying point $x \in M$ for a differentiable manifold $M$ - but I haven't given it much thought.